# Window form textbox not updating from another file

Tags: c#, winforms

I have two files, form1.cs and parser.cs. When I called my update method for NPCLogger.Text in the form1.cs file it works. but when I call it from parser.cs it does not? I've tried a lot of other solutions online and can't seem to get it working.

form1.cs

```
    public void updateConsole(string text)
    {
        NPCLogger.Text += text;
    }

    private void ParseButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Parser parser = new Parser();
        string link = UserLink.Text;
        parser.Parsing(link);
        updateConsole("12312"); // this works
    }
```

parser.cs

```
    public class Parser : Form
{
    public bool debug = false;
    public string aggroRadius = null;

    public void Parsing(string userLink)
    {
        updateConsole("This does not work");
```

Comment: Surely this is producing an error, since `Parser` doesn't *have* an `updateConsole` method.  (At least not in the code shown.)  What does the error tell you?

Comment: I get no error while I'm running it, the code is working for the most part other than my RichTextBox not getting updated

Answer (score 0):

The compiler error you're seeing (but not including in the question...) is telling you that there *is no* `updateConsole` method in the `Parser` class.  (Unless you've added one, and didn't include *that* in the question.  In which case... what on Earth does that method do and why are you expecting a method on a different class to be invoked?)

When you attempt to call a method that's in the `Parser` class from the `Form1` class, note how you do that:

```
parser.Parsing(link);
```

You don't just call `Parsing(link)` by itself, you call it *on the `parser` variable*, which is an instance of the `Parser` class.  So, when you want to call a method that's in the `Form1` class from the `Parser` class, why do you expect it to be any different?

You need a reference to your `Form1` object.  Given the code shown, probably the simplest way is to add it to the `Parser` constructor:

```
private Form1 form1Instance { get; set; }

public Parser(Form1 form1)
{
    this.form1Instance = form1;
}
```

And pass the reference when calling the constructor:

```
Parser parser = new Parser(this);
```

Then, in `Parser`, you can use that property to reference the object:

```
this.form1Instance.updateConsole("This does not work");
```

---

As an aside... You're digging yourself into a rabbit hole.  Now you have two forms trying to directly interact with each other's UI controls.  It's going to get unwieldy quickly.

A form should be responsible for its own UI controls.  Models/objects (*not* forms) should encapsulate the core logic of the application.  Any given form would invoke that logic and use the returned result to update its UI.